# Как сделать копию списка

Tags: python

Требуется сделать копию списка K, при чём надо копировать список с индекса 2 по 17

Comment: и на будущее, здесь вам не будут помогать от нечего делать, помощь приветствуется только в тех случаях, когда автор вопроса пытался сам, но у него не получилось..

Comment: @finally конечно же будут, если вопрос легкий, ради репутации, прямо как вы сделали сейчас)

Comment: @whizz169 В принципе в этом вопросе ничего плохого нет.

Comment: @whizz169 вопрос не стоял как требование решить какую либо задачу или подобное, тут просто незнание самых начал, так что прям принципиального тут нет

Answer (score 1):

```py
a = [i for i in range(20)]
a1 = a[2:18] # это если под "по 17" вы имеете в виду включая 17
a1 = a[2:17] # а это если нет
```

Comment: `a = [i for i in range(20)` это костыль `a = range(20)`

Comment: @VictorsaysReinstateMonica для наглядности

Comment: Какая тут наглядность?

Comment: @VictorsaysReinstateMonica лично мне кажется, что человеку, который не знает что такое срез, проще будет понять "и для и в размере двадцати", чем "размер двадцать"

Comment: Если человек не знает что такое срез, то такие сложные синтаксические фигуры и подавно. Тогда уж так:`for i in range(20): a.append(i)` Хотя это просто ужас уже  :)

Comment: @VictorsaysReinstateMonica какой же это костыль, если на выходе совсем разные объекты?

Comment: @Эникейщик тут согласен, но тогда можно так: `list(range(20))`

Comment: @Эникейщик Такое положение дел (отдельный тип) только в питоне 3.x, а в python 2:`>>> type(range(100))   
<type 'list'>`